Device.createBuffer( usage:GPUBufferUsage.VERTEX ) in every frame , minutes later , browser get wrong
I try to code a simple paint example with webgpu , so , in every mousemove , arrayData.length is changing. I keep an array storage all points(vec2 array) , I create new GPUBuffer with this points array in every frame,because I want to change the gpuBuffer.size whitch is readonly.
At last I get an Error :
RangeError: Failed to execute 'createBuffer' on 'GPUDevice': createBuffer failed, size is too large for the implementation when mappedAtCreation == true
const data = new Float32Array( [ 0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4 ] );

async function frame () {

    const commandEncoder = device.createCommandEncoder();

    ... ...

    const vertexBuffer = device.createBuffer( {
        size: data.byteLength,
        usage: GPUBufferUsage.VERTEX,
        mappedAtCreation: true
    } );

    //@ts-ignore
    const dst = new data.constructor( vertexBuffer.getMappedRange() );
    dst.set( data );
    vertexBuffer.unmap();

    const passEncoder = commandEncoder.beginRenderPass( renderPassDescriptor );
    passEncoder.setPipeline( pipeline );
    passEncoder.setVertexBuffer( 0, vertexBuffer );

    passEncoder.draw( data.length / 2 );
    passEncoder.end();

    device.queue.submit( [ commandEncoder.finish() ] );
    
    // I try to destory the buffer after finish , it is no useful
    vertexBuffer.destroy();

    requestAnimationFrame( frame );
}

I want to update the vertexBuffer in mosemove(in every frame), at present, i create new GPUBuffer , it doesn't seem to work
